# What is qualcomm.qti.autoregistration process for?

Tags: security, internet

I was using 'netstat' for Android and I discovered many processes called 'com.qualcomm.qti.autoregistration' LISTENING on several UDP ports (IPv4 and IPv6)

I have a OnePlus 3t running Android 8.0 and OxygenOS 5.0.2.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: These are processes related to the functionality of your device hardware.  _com.qualcomm.qti.autoregistration_ is the full package name of the process, where "qti" stands for "Qualcomm Technologies, Inc.  The "*.34xxx" numbers are probably ports.  I'm unsure what the  "autoregistration" process actually does, however.  My hunch is that it has to do with WiFi calling.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already knew about the qti and ports part. But I couldn't find info about the autoregistration process.